# Extending a custom Entry using Maui Partial Handlers overrides default property mappings

Tags: maui

I am converting my Custom Renderers from Xamarin.Forms to Maui using Handlers.
Basically I define CustomEntry extending Entry like below

```
public class CustomEntry : Entry
    {
        public bool IsNumeric { get; set; }
        public bool IsDouble { get; set; } = true;

        public int MaxDecimalDigits { get; set; }
        #region Constructors

        public CustomEntry()
            : base()
        {
            MaxDecimalDigits = 2;
            IsNumeric = true;
            IsDouble = true;
            Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;
            // Set the events.
            base.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public static readonly BindableProperty FormatStringValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create("FormatString", typeof(string), typeof(CustomEntry),
             defaultValue: string.Empty, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public string FormatString
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(FormatStringValueProperty);
            set => SetValue(FormatStringValueProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty MaxValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create("MaxValue", typeof(double?), typeof(CustomEntry), defaultValue: null, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public double? MaxValue
        {
            get => (double?)GetValue(MaxValueProperty);
            set => SetValue(MaxValueProperty, value);
        }


        public static readonly BindableProperty MinValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create("MinValue", typeof(double?), typeof(CustomEntry), defaultValue: 0.0, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public double? MinValue
        {
            get => (double?)GetValue(MinValueProperty);
            set => SetValue(MinValueProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty MaxLengthProperty = BindableProperty.Create("MaxLength", typeof(int?), typeof(CustomEntry), defaultValue: null, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

        public int? MaxLength
        {
            get => (int?)GetValue(MaxLengthProperty);
            set => SetValue(MaxLengthProperty, value);
        }
        public static BindableProperty BorderColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create("BorderColor", typeof(Color), typeof(CustomEntry), defaultValue: Colors.Transparent);

        public Color BorderColor
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(BorderColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value);
        }
```

then I created the handlers like below

```
public partial class CustomEntryHandler
{
    public static PropertyMapper<CustomEntry, CustomEntryHandler> PropertyMapper = new PropertyMapper<CustomEntry, CustomEntryHandler>(ViewHandler.ViewMapper)
    {
#if __ANDROID__
        [nameof(CustomEntry.BorderWidth)] = UpdateBackground,
        [nameof(CustomEntry.BorderColor)] = UpdateBackground,
        [nameof(CustomEntry.BorderRadius)] = UpdateBackground,
        [nameof(CustomEntry.BackgroundColor)] = UpdateBackground,
        [nameof(CustomEntry.LeftPadding)] = UpdatePadding,
        [nameof(CustomEntry.RightPadding)] = UpdatePadding,
        [nameof(CustomEntry.HorizontalTextAlignment)] = UpdateTextAlignment,
#elif IOS || MACCATALYST
        [nameof(CustomEntry.BorderWidth)] = UpdateBorderWidth,
        [nameof(CustomEntry.BorderColor)] = UpdateBorderColor,
        [nameof(CustomEntry.BorderRadius)] = UpdateBorderRadius,
        [nameof(CustomEntry.LeftPadding)] = UpdateLeftPadding,
        [nameof(CustomEntry.RightPadding)] = UpdateRightPadding,
#endif
    };

    public CustomEntryHandler() : base(PropertyMapper)
    {
    }
}
```

for Ios and Mac

```
[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
public partial class CustomEntryHandler : ViewHandler<CustomEntry, MauiTextField>
{
    #region Parent override

    protected override MauiTextField CreatePlatformView() => new MauiTextField(VirtualView.Frame);

    protected override void ConnectHandler(MauiTextField platformView)
    {
        platformView.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
        base.ConnectHandler(platformView);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Utility methods

    public static void UpdateBorderWidth(CustomEntryHandler handler, CustomEntry customEntry)
    {
        handler.PlatformView.UpdateBorder(customEntry);  
    }

    public static void UpdateBorderColor(CustomEntryHandler handler, CustomEntry customEntry)
    {
        handler.PlatformView.UpdateBorder(customEntry);
    }
    
    protected override void DisconnectHandler(MauiTextField platformView)
    {
        // Perform any native view cleanup here
        platformView.Dispose();
        base.DisconnectHandler(platformView);
    }
    
    public static void UpdateBorderRadius(CustomEntryHandler handler, CustomEntry customEntry)
    {
        handler.PlatformView.UpdateBorder(customEntry);
    }

    public static void UpdateLeftPadding(CustomEntryHandler handler, CustomEntry customEntry)
    {
        var leftPaddingView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, customEntry.LeftPadding, 0));
        handler.PlatformView.LeftView = leftPaddingView;
        handler.PlatformView.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
    }

    public static void UpdateRightPadding(CustomEntryHandler handler, CustomEntry customEntry)
    {
        var rightPaddingView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, customEntry.RightPadding, 0));
        handler.PlatformView.RightView = rightPaddingView;
        handler.PlatformView.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

finally I have registered in MauiProgram as suggested

```
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()                 
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            })
            .ConfigureMauiHandlers((handlers) =>
        {
#if ANDROID
                handlers.AddHandler(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryHandler));
#elif IOS
            handlers.AddHandler(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryHandler));
#endif
        });
```

It doesn't work as expected. For example, i don't see the things i have defined in the CustomEntry constructor. They are overridden for some reason, as opposite of XF Renderers. I am guessing this has something to do with the `AppendingToMapping` thing using the other approach.
But I want to use Partial class approach as above. How to achieve this?
There is an example on MS Github [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Porting-Custom-Renderers-to-Handlers) but they are inheriting from a View? why? I want to extend precisely Entry, not any View.

Comment: IMHO, this is a huge hole in the design of custom handlers. There are situations where I ended up copy/pasting A LOT of source code from Maui, to make what I thought would be a simple customization. Not sure what to do about it.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve what and why are you copy pasting? normally looks not complicated but obviously something not really working as expected.

Comment: Its been a year since I did it. When you mentioned "property mappings", I recalled running into a problem because I did not have access to internal types that are used in defining the built-in functionality.  Gave up trying to add a handler to whatever Element I was customizing. Defined my own version of the element from scratch, copy-pasting most of the classes used in defining Maui's version of that element. Which was a lot more files than one would expect, because one file would be dependent on a bunch of other source files not accessible from the outside.

Comment: [Ali's FreakyControls](https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls) do a good amount of customization; may be something useful there. Also [search `github maui custom controls`](https://www.google.com/search?q=github+maui+custom+controls).